# Make a SQL query with unknown number of ANDs

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

Imagine I would like to search my database for one or a combination of fields. Now I do not know how many of these fields I have. So I made a function which takes them all as argument but empty Strings for the ones which are not applicable (or 0 for ints)

```
findSometing(int serial, String att1, String att2, String att3)
```

Now when I'm making the query `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE` I cannot determine where to put my `AND` commands. Does anyone have a good solution to this problem? I can do it with a lot of if statements but thats messy. 
Just to add I HAVE to use JDBC.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [MyBatis](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html)?

Comment: Are you just wanting to check for equality of each column to the corresponding argument passed in?

Comment: Yes if that agrument is no Empty. If it is empty I want to ignore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1=1"; 
if(a!=null)
    query+="AND a=?";
if(b!=null)
    query+="AND b=?";

PreparedStatement stmt ...
```

Comment: omg THANK you very much. I that will make it hell of a lot simpler

Comment: It is better to use StringBuilder for dynamic string manupulations.